# flatlist slow performance on large data react native

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react native and I'm having some performance problem with flatlist in React Native Expo. On my screen I'm displaying a list of contacts and I want them to be selected or deselected and I have managed to achieve that part but the problem is that it takes a lot of visibility time to check the contacts or to uncheck them. Making the screen not very user friendly. I have tried a lot of solutions that I've found on internet regarding this problem but none of them had worked. Hope someone can help me. Below I'll attach the code!

```
function ContactList() {
  const [itemChecked, setItemChecked] = useState([]);
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [checkedBox, setCheckedBox] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Contacts.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (status === 'granted') {
        const { data } = await Contacts.getContactsAsync({
          fields: [Contacts.Fields.PhoneNumbers],
          // fields: [Contacts.Fields.Name],
        });
        if (data.length > 0) {
          setContacts(data);
          setFilter(data);
          // console.log('contact', contacts[1]);
          // console.log('filter', filter);
        }
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  const searchFilter = (text) => {
    if (text) {
      const newData = contacts.filter((item) => {
        const itemData = item.name ? item.name.toUpperCase() : ''.toUpperCase();

        const textData = text.toUpperCase();
        return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
      });
      setFilter(newData);
      setSearch(text);
    } else {
      setFilter(contacts);
      setSearch(text);
    }
  };

  const onChangeValue = (item, index) => {
    if (itemChecked.includes(item.phoneNumbers[0].digits)) {
      itemChecked.splice(itemChecked.indexOf(item.phoneNumbers[0].digits), 1);
    } else {
      itemChecked.push(item.phoneNumbers[0].digits);
      setCheckedBox(true);
    }

    setItemChecked(itemChecked);
    console.log(itemChecked);
    // console.log(item);
  };

  const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <ScrollView>
          <TouchableOpacity style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1 }}>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, borderTopWidth: 0.5, borderTopColor: 'grey', marginBottom: 15 }}>
              <Text onPress={() => setChecked(true)} style={{ fontSize: 20, marginHorizontal: 10 }}>
                {item.name + ' '}
              </Text>
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 17, marginHorizontal: 10, marginTop: 5, color: 'grey' }}>
                {item.phoneNumbers && item.phoneNumbers[0] && item.phoneNumbers[0].number}
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, borderTopWidth: 0.5, borderTopColor: 'grey' }}>
              {itemChecked.includes(item.phoneNumbers[0].digits) === false ? (
                <CheckBox
                  style={{ width: 15, height: 15 }}
                  right={true}
                  checked={false}
                  onPress={() => {
                    onChangeValue(item, index);
                  }}
                />
              ) : (
                <CheckBox
                  style={{ width: 15, height: 15, paddingTop: 8 }}
                  right={true}
                  checked={true}
                  onPress={() => {
                    onChangeValue(item, index);
                  }}
                />
              )}
            </View>
            {/* <Post postJson={item} isGroupAdmin={isGroupAdmin} user={user} /> */}
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View
          style={{
            height: 40,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            backgroundColor: '#eeeeee',
            width: '90%',
            marginHorizontal: 20,
            marginTop: 15,
            borderRadius: 10,
          }}
        >
          <Feather name="search" size={20} color="grey" style={{ position: 'absolute', left: 32 }} />
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Search"
            placeholderTextColor="#949494"
            style={{
              left: 20,
              paddingHorizontal: 35,
              fontSize: 20,
            }}
            value={search}
            onChangeText={(text) => {
              searchFilter(text);
              setSearch(text);
            }}
          />
        </View>
        <FlatList
          style={{ marginTop: 15 }}
          data={contacts && filter}
          keyExtractor={(item) => `key-${item.id.toString()}`}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          refreshing={true}
          initialNumToRender={10}
          ListEmptyComponent={<Text message="No contacts found." />}
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});

export default ContactList;
```

Comment: This probably isn't your core issue, but it is against convention to call two setState functions in a useEffect hook, as it causes extra renders. Maybe you can bundle those into a single state? https://levelup.gitconnected.com/react-hooks-gotchas-setstate-in-async-effects-d2fd84b02305

Comment: Thank you for replying, I did try to remove the second state from the useEffect to see if that was causing the problem but it's still slow on rendering the checked or unchecked button even with one state in useEffect. What would you think about the logic onChangeValue function? Is there anything I can do to improve that?